# Javascript: Getting greeting messages according to time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display greeting message according to time.

For that I have created date object and getting hrs and displaying each message but due to some error I am not getting greeting message according to time. can anyone help me ?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>trail6</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

    var today = new Date()
    var curHr = today.getHours()

    if (curHr >= 0 && curHr < 6) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'What are you doing that early?';
    } else if (curHr >= 6 && curHr <= 12) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Morning';
    } else if (curHr >= 12 && curHr < 17) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Afternoon';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Evening';
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your error? And did you console.log(curHr) to see what it says? You also are executing both if statements at the same time. When the time is 12. (curHr >= 6 && curHr <= 12) and (curHr >= 12 && curHr < 17)

Comment: For starters, you have two conditions in your if/else that will return true if the curHr variable is 12.

Comment: @RobertWade it does not matter, the first condition will be true and the second won't be entered

Comment: In my code it's not showing greeting according to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>trail6</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

    var today = new Date()
    var curHr = today.getHours()

    if (curHr >= 0 && curHr < 6) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'What are you doing that early?';
    } else if (curHr >= 6 && curHr < 12) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Morning';
    } else if (curHr >= 12 && curHr < 17) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Afternoon';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Evening';
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I got rid of the = sign before your first 12, otherwise your code executes correctly. And displays Good Afternoon to me. I console logged it, it works fine and displays accordingly. It must be Noon where you are at. As this is the only way your code could break, before the fix. Glad to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 7):

So you need to divide your day into **4 sets** of 6 hours each, starting at `0`...

### Let's math...

Convert the result of `hour / 24 * 4` and use it as the message array **index**

```js
var greet = [
  'What are you doing that early?',
  'Good Morning',
  'Good Afternoon',
  'Good Evening'
][ parseInt(new Date().getHours() / 24 * 4) ];


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greet;
```

```html
<div id=demo></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Works fine for me...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>trail6</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

    var today = new Date()
    var curHr = today.getHours()

    if (curHr >= 0 && curHr < 6) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'What are you doing that early?';
    } else if (curHr >= 6 && curHr <= 12) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Morning';
    } else if (curHr >= 12 && curHr < 17) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Afternoon';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Evening';
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not showing greeting message according to time.

Comment: And what did you change?

Comment: Nothing at all.